# LEFT HAND Piano Fingering logic

Tags: technique, fingering

Does anyone have a resource, Basic fingering Logic and left hand posturing for LH Arpeggios
including

1. Pivot of wrist
2. Shape and position of left hand throughout arpeggio.

Thanks

Comment: If there is anything (and on this site, we don't recommend) it will be basic. Everyone's physiology is different, so one 'perfect' method will be someone else's disaster.

Comment: But you can look up all the related questions on the right edge of this site: green and grey boxes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just asking for resources. Search Google for IMSLP and scale and arpeggios. You should find things like https://imslp.org/wiki/Mastering_the_Scales_and_Arpeggios_(Cooke%2C_James_Francis) piano methods with fingerings for scales, arpeggios, etc.